# Samung S-Pen detection in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, easeljs, stylus-pen

I am developing a cordova app with ionic. I have some drawing functionality using canvas. Is there any way to detect whether user is drawing with finger or a S-Pen(Stylus) provided by samsung with mobile/tablet.

Comment: Either find a plugin or develop one yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I havn't found any plugin related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant, you can only diferenciate between touch events or keyboard/mouse events, so S Pen should trigger the touch ones. The only way is to create a plugin based on the S-Pen SDK provided by Samsung

Comment: I think finger touch or S Pen touch both will fire touch events. Can i differenciate between them?

Comment: Only with the s-pen SDK, SO you would need to embeed it in a cordova plugin to achieve that